# Получение хоста сетевого коннекта

Tags: android, java, сеть

Возможно ли при коннекте приложения на определенный хост через интернет заблочить его(соединение)? Былобы замечательно если бы это можно было реализовать через приемники широковешательных намерений.

Comment: >> приемники широковешательных намерений   ???????????????

Answer (score 2):

Возможно, если вы имеете доступ к машине, лежащей на маршруте следования пакетов от одной машины к другой. Делается через настройку пакетного фильтра.